# Multiple INNER JOIN SQL ACCESS SYNTAX

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch data from `table(six_attendance, five_attendance)` via `INNER JOIN` with `table(users)`. Here is what I have tried:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM
(users 
INNER JOIN six_attendance 
ON users.username = six_attendance.username)
INNER JOIN five_attendance 
ON users.username = five_attendance.username
WHERE six_attendance.username OR five_attendance.username ='$reg_no'");
```

Comment: `WHERE  six_attendance.username='$reg_no' OR five_attendance.username ='$reg_no'` you also have an extra set of parantheses inside

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM
users 
INNER JOIN six_attendance 
ON users.username = six_attendance.username
INNER JOIN five_attendance 
ON users.username = five_attendance.username
WHERE six_attendance.username='$reg_no' OR five_attendance.username ='$reg_no'");
```

Comment: Rmoving the extra parentheses which are added to the query changes nothing to the out put.

Comment: You have to add ='$reg_no' to the first requirement as well.

Comment: When doing a double inner join like this, you will first get all instances from six_attendance, and than combine that will all instances from five_attendance. Could you be more specific with what you want to do?

Comment: I have students details in `users` table and there semester attendance are recorded in each `six_attendance` and `five_attendance` tables, both mentioned table are joined on 'username' to the `users` table. Now I want to check the attendance of each student based on the 'username' and fetch data from both tables.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @AhmadReshadZazai Isn't it Left join you want to do then? Is username unique in six_attendance and five_attendance?

Comment: @Linkan Thanks, I got a solution.